# Element doesn't come back to original position?

Tags: jquery

I have an element with `bottom: 10`. I want it to change to 20 while hovering on it. And come back to 10 on mouse out:

```
$('.home-box-caption a').hover(function() {
  $('.home-box-caption a').animate({
    bottom: 20
  }, 200, function() {
    bottom: 10
  });
});
```

Right now it just remain in 20.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not quite using `.hover()` correctly.

`.hover(function[, function])`

```
var $targets = $('.home-box-caption').find('a');
$targets.hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    bottom: 20
  }, 200);
}, function(){
  $(this).animate({
    bottom: 10
  }, 200);
});
```

Consider using the `this` keyword (unless your intention is to animate all `a` elements under `.home-box-caption`), or storing those elements in a variable so you don't have to requery the DOM each time.

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Oh yes, I just awnt to animate the current element

Comment: @alexchenco - I have updated my answer to reflect just targeting the current element, using `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

You might like to animate the element back on mouseout using hover's 2nd parameter like this

```
        $('.home-box-caption a').hover(function () {
           $(this).animate({
              bottom: 20
           }, 200)
        }, function () {
           $(this).animate({
              bottom: 10
           }, 200)
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place the second animation as the second argument of `hover`:

```
$('.home-box-caption a').hover(
  function(){
    //this is invoked when the mouse ENTERS the element
    $(this).animate({top: 140}, 200);
  },
  function(){
    //this is invoked when the mouse LEAVES the element
    $(this).animate({top: 150}, 200);
  }
);
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/fnpuC/)

The `hover` method supports to callbacks: `.hover( handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject) )`. See http://api.jquery.com/hover/

The first will be invoked, when the mouse enters the elements, the second when it leaves the  element.

The `animate` method also supports a callback: `.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )` but this `complete` callback will be invoked, when the first animation is completed.